# C++ reference to a copy-constructed object

Tags: c++, reference, constructor

Hey this is a really basic question and but I got confused about it. Say I created an object

`MyObject a`.

It comes with a copy constructor, so I know I can do this:

`MyObject b(a);`
But can I do this?

`MyObject& b(a);`

And if I do this:

`MyObject b = a;` what is in `b`? Apology if this question is too fundamental to be bothered posting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doing `MyObject& b(a)` has nothing to do with the copy constructor. It just creates `b` which is a reference to the object `a`. Nothing is copied. Think of `b` as an alias for the object `a`. You can use `b` and `a` equivalently from then on to refer to the same object.

`MyObject b = a;` will use the copy constructor, just as `MyObject b(a);` would.

---

There are two forms of initialisation: `T x = a;` is known as *copy-initialization*; `T x(a)` and `T x{a}` are known as *direct-initialization*.

When `T` is a reference type, it doesn't matter which type of initialisation is used. Both have the same effect.

When `T` is a class type, we have two possibilities:

1. If the initialisation is *direct-initialization* (`MyClass b(a);`), or, if it is *copy-initialization* with `a` being derived from or the same type as `T` (`MyClass b = a;`): an applicable constructor of `T` is chosen to construct the object.

   As you can see, both of your examples fall in this category of class type initialisers.
2. If the initialisation is any other form of *copy-initialization*, any user-defined conversion sequence will be considered followed by a direct-initialization. A user-defined conversion sequence is basically any sequence of standard conversions with a single conversion constructor thrown in there.

   If `c` were of `Foo` class type and there was a conversion constructor from `Foo` to `MyClass`, then `MyClass b = c;` would be equivalent to `MyClass b(MyClass(c));`.

So basically, if the source and destination types are the same, both forms of initialisation are equivalent. If a conversion is required, they are not. A simple example to show this is:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Bar { };

struct Foo
{
  Foo(const Foo& f) { std::cout << "Copy" << std::endl; }
  Foo(const Bar& b) { std::cout << "Convert" << std::endl; }
};

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
  Bar b;
  Foo f1(b);
  std::cout << "----" << std::endl;
  Foo f2 = b;
  return 0;
}
```

The output for this program (with copy elision disabled) is:

```
Convert
----
Convert
Copy
```

Of course, there are lots of other types of initialisations too (list initialisation, character arrays, aggregates, etc.).

Comment: just making sure i get it, so `MyObject& b = a` is absolutely equivalent to `MyObject& b(a)` and `MyObject b(a)` to `MyOjbect b = a' ?

Comment: @user1861088 not really, search for copy initialization vs direct initialization.

Comment: @user1861088 For the reference type, always, yes. For the class type, it depends. In this case, yes.

Comment: @user1861088: Maybe this simple example could help you too: http://ideone.com/CDwFDO

Comment: Excellent post @sftrabbit.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my view:

References are tied to someones else's storage, whenever u access a reference, you’re accessing that storage. References cannot be assigned to null because of the fact that they are just an aliases. A reference must be initialized when it is created. (Pointers can be initialized at any time.)

so when you say

```
    MyObject& b(a);
```

compiler allocates a piece of storage b, and ties the reference to a.

when you say

```
    MyObject b = a;
```

you pass a reference of a to the copy constructor and creates new b from it. Note that its a deep copy only if you have a copy constructor written for it. Otherwise it calls the default copy constructor which results in a shallow copy.

and when you say

```
   a = b; // after creating these objects
```

it translates as Object::operator=(const Object&), thus A.operator=(B) is called (invoke simple copy, not copy constructor!)

Comment: When you say `MyObject &b(a)` the compiler doesn't allocate a piece of storage `a` and ties the reference to that piece of storage. It allocates a reference called `b` and ties it to `a`. And it's **not** accurate to say that a copy-constructor results in a deep copy. It may - but it's not required.

Comment: @Nik: I edited my answer. Good catch for deep copy, i was assuming that he had a valid copy constructor.